# XmlReader behaves correctly on Win 8, fails on Win 2008

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

Validating an XML file via XmlReader I correctly get the following error:

The element 'Contact' has invalid child element 'ContactEmail'. List of possible elements expected: 'ContactPhone'.

```
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
            settings.Schemas = sc;
            settings.ValidationEventHandler += vh;
            settings.IgnoreComments = true;
            settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;

            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlPath, settings);

            // loop follows
```

The bad XML look like this

```
        <Contact>
            <ContactName/>
            <ContactEmail/>
        </Contact>
```

And should look like this

```
        <Contact>
            <ContactName/>
            <ContactPhone/>
            <ContactEmail/>
        </Contact>
```

So far so good.

Move the code, schemas, and XML file from Windows 8 to our 2008 server, and the XML error is ignored, the file validates as good.

Compiling on the target server, no change.
Setting the build type to 64, no change.

What else should I look for?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of 2008 server?

Comment: Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1

Comment: **SOLVED** Dropped the target framework from 3.5 down to 3.0, and the code works in both environment.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

Dropped the target framework from 3.5 down to 3.0, and the code works in both environment.
(I would still love to hear from someone who can tell me why it failed inconsistently at 3.5)